# Iterate a collection backwards in Pharo Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I'm new using Pharo and I'm trying to iterate over an `OrderedCollection`, but starting from the end.

For example:

```smalltalk
| c |
c := OrderedCollection new.
c add: (1).
c add: (2).
c add: (3).
c do: [ :each | Transcript show: each ; cr ]
```

The result is `1 2 3` but I want `3 2 1`.

Is it possible or do I have to use another kind of collection?

Comment: Try `c reverseDo: [ etc ]`. Best of luck.

Comment: You can also use `Transcript logCr: each`, and when inside a method `self logCr: each`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To iterate an OrderedCollection in reverse order you can use the `reverseDo:` method, e.g.

```
c reverseDo: [ :each | Transcript show: each; cr ].
```